# JQuery TableSorter 2.25 (Mottie fork) w/ Scroller: Programmatically scroll to row?

Tags: jquery, tablesorter

I've been using the [Mottie fork of the JQuery TableSorter](https://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/) plugin for a while now, and it's pretty phenomenal. I'm using the ["scroller" widget](https://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/example-widget-scroller.html) to make the table scrollable vertically as well as horizontally while keeping some fixed columns on the left.

Here's the question: Is there a way to programmatically scroll to a particular row? e.g. "myTable.scrollToRow(40)"? A pixel offset would be perfectly acceptable too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what interface is being used to allow the user to scroll to a particular row, but you can use the following code to set the scroll ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/mqv16pd4/43/)):

HTML (used in demo)

```
Scroll to row: <button type="button">20</button> <button type="button">40</button>
```

Script

```
$('button').click(function(){
    var $scroller = $('.tablesorter-scroller-table'),
    row = parseInt( $(this).text(), 10 ),
    position = $table.find('tbody tr').eq(row).position();
  $scroller.scrollTop( $scroller.scrollTop() + position.top );
});
```

Comment: That did the trick very nicely, even working with the fixed columns!